# How does global variable work in Angular, Ionic

Tags: angular, spring, ionic-framework

Perhaps this is a dumb question to ask but I am new to front-end development and come from a backend background. Doing things as so in a java class is not threadsafe if the object created is a singleton that is shared across all threads

```
class{
  String username;
}
```

In Angular what happens if we have

```
export class RegistrationPage implements OnInit {

  firstname: string = "";

}
```

Are components in Angular singletons?

Comment: same thing as in java or any other programming language that has concept of class, what exactly is the question? if it is thread safe? depends how you use it, maybe dont create to many async calls mutating state of the same object and everything will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally components are not singleton. And if you declare a `public` variable in a component, it can only be accessed from the files of the same module(for example html file).
But services are singleton. You can access `public` variables declared in the services globally.

Is that the answer you are looking for?

Comment: What happens if multiple users connecting to my angular server use the same variable from services. Will there be a concurrency issue?. And to your point on components, I assume every component is bound to an user. Is that correct?

Comment: Aren't you using angular for front-end development? If yes, then how can multiple users connect to a single instance of the application? It's basically running on a single device and there is no concurrency issue! Am i getting you wrong?

Comment: That's what I thought. Angular runs on a single device or browser so there is no concurrency issue.

Comment: Yes that's right. Please kindly mark my answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: Note that angular services are not always singleton : there is one instance per module where it is provided. It is a singleton only if provided in app module or made injectable and tagged with providedIn: 'root'

Comment: That's right. Thanks for completing my response.